# Cannot access resource with getResource() in JavaFX project

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, resources, javafx-8

I know this seems to be a common theme but **no solution on StackOverflow worked** for me thus far. See below for all I've tried.

**The issue:** The `getResource()` method isn't able to retrieve resources for my project regardless of the paths I try.

**Project structure(s):** The resource in question is `mainWindow.fxml` and the class I try to retrieve it in is `Main.java`.

```
src/
|-- main/
    |-- java/
        |-- app/
            |-- myproject/
                |> FXMLController.java
                |> Main.java
                |> package-info.java
                |> styles.css
                |> mainWindow.fxml
        |> module-info.java
    |-- resources/
|-- test/
|> build.gradle
|> gradlew
|> gradlew.bat
|> settings.gradle
```

However, note that I also tried putting the resource inside `resources/` and inside `resources/fxml/` and tried all paths (see below) with each.

**Paths I tried:** The following paths have been tried with all the paths described above, and both with `getClass().getResource()` **and** `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()`.

- `mainWindow.fxml`
- `/mainWindow.fxml`
- `fxml/mainWindow.fxml`
- `/fxml/mainWindow.fxml`

If it helps, I'm on Windows and using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

Comment: don't randomly try all paths you can think of (why would you prepend fxml to any path?) - instead read the api doc of getResource carefully and do exactly what it specifies as valid path param. Hint: it's a path to a _package_ (either relative or absolute) If you are still stuck, come back with a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: Look at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#specify_output_path maybe you set something wrong there

Comment: @kleopatra I prepended fxml to paths when I tried using a subdirectory called fxml to place the file. I checked the docs before asking the question and nothing led me to a working solution. More specific advice would be appreciated. I can provide the content of any file if it helps. On that note, I don't know what's missing to make the question more reproducible.

Comment: everything is missing to make it reproducible: the main, the controller, the fxml, the error stacktrace, the module-info (package-info and css are not important). And mind: _not_ your production code but a _minimal example_, written just to demonstrate the problem. That said: verify that the resource files are where you expect them to be, that is copied over to the bin hierarchy (or whereever intelli has them) - given your source hierarchy, they must be in the same package as Main.class

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that we use on JavaFX 8 applications it will work just great
We name all our Anchor Panes with an fx-id. This code will NOT work if you are making a JavaFX with Maven application. The toChildView() is the Action Event of a Button

```
    private void toChildView() throws IOException{
    stage = (Stage)parentTVPane.getScene().getWindow();// pane you are ON
    childTVPane = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("childtableview.fxml"));// pane you are GOING TO
    Scene scene = new Scene(childTVPane);// pane you are GOING TO
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("diary.css").toExternalForm());
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.setTitle("Diary Entries by Date Entered and Title"); 
    stage.show();
    stage.sizeToScene();
    stage.centerOnScreen();  
}
```